# Como posso converter uma DataTable para um objeto dinâmico?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Como posso converter um `DataTable` em um `IEnumerable<dynamicObject>`?

Por exemplo, quero converter qualquer `DataTable`

```
ID | Name          DI | emaN
---------    ou    ---------
 1 | x              2 | x
 2 | y              1 | y
```

Em uma lista de objetos

```
// list 1      (ex 1)             // list 2    (ex 2)
{                                 {
  { ID = 1, Name = "x" }            { DI = 2, emaN = "x" }
  { ID = 2, Name = "y" }            { DI = 1, emaN = "y" }
}                                 }
```

Então eu posso acessar os valores como se fossem propriedades.

```
list1.First().ID    // 1
list2.First().emaN  // "x"
```

Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para seu primeiro exemplo em especifico bastaria:

```
dataTable1.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => new { ID = dr["ID"], Name = dr["Name"] });
```

Mas para uma solução mais genérica pode se utilizar o (pouco conhecido) [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx):

```
static IEnumerable<dynamic> ObjetoDinamico(this DataTable dt)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        dynamic dinamico = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)dinamico)[dc.ColumnName] = dr[dc];
        yield return dinamico;
    }
}
```

Exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<dynamic> ObjetoDinamico(this DataTable dt)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                dynamic dinamico = new ExpandoObject();
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                    ((IDictionary<string, object>)dinamico)[dc.ColumnName] = dr[dc];
                yield return dinamico;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt1.Rows.Add(1, "x");
            dt1.Rows.Add(2, "y");

            var dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("DI", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("emaN", typeof(string));
            dt2.Rows.Add(2, "x");
            dt2.Rows.Add(1, "y");

            Console.WriteLine(dt1.ObjetoDinamico().First().ID); // 1
            Console.WriteLine(dt2.ObjetoDinamico().First().emaN); // "x"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Existe algum projeto que foi usado isso como exemplo pra facilitar?

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa biblioteca](https://github.com/tallesl/ToObject) ;)